Possible to find values A and B when C and D are known?
Apologies if this is a simple question but I am a relatively new person to cryptography.
Given A XOR (B XOR C) = D is it possible to find the value of either A or B if only C and D are known?
Example (sorry it's in bits)
A = 1010
B = 0010
C = 1111
D = 0111
Research effort: I've been staring at a post-it note full of 0s and 1s until I got a headache and came here if that counts.

This is impossible in general. Rearrange to get
$$
A\oplus B= C\oplus D :=E,
$$
so for any right hand side $E$ and any $B$ you can find an $A$ that will work. For $n$ bit strings, this gives $2^n$ pairs
$$
(A,B)=(E\oplus B,B)
$$
that work as $B$ ranges over all possible $n$ bit strings.
